# select() on half-open socket does not return on close()?

Tags: linux, sockets, select

I'm doing `select()` on a blocking socket with no timeout `select(sock+1, &rfd, NULL, NULL, NULL)`.

This happens in a thread whose objective is to dispatch incoming data. Another surveillance thread is managing a keep alive with the peer and when it detects a dead connection, it would close the socket.

I was expecting `select()` to return with `-1` in that case. It does that on Windows but never on Linux, so the dispatch thread is locked forever when the peer disappear non-gracefully. For completeness, there is pending data to be transmitted on that, I've tried to play with `SO_LINGER` but that does not change anything.

The problem can be solved by setting a timeout in `select()` and in that case after close and timeout, `select()` ultimately exits with `-1`, but I thought, reading the doc, that `select()` with no timeout would still exit on close, even when the peer is not responding.

Do I misuse `select()` or is there a better way to handle half-open sockets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you misuse the `select`. The `man select` states:

> If a file descriptor being monitored by select() is closed in another thread, the result is unspecified. On some UNIX systems, select() unblocks and returns, with an indication that the file descriptor is ready (a subsequent I/O operation will likely fail with an error, unless another the file descriptor reopened between the time select() returned and the I/O operations was performed).  On Linux (and some other systems), closing the file descriptor in another thread has no effect on select().  In summary, any application that relies on a particular behavior in  this scenario must be considered buggy.

So you cannot close connection from other thread. Unfortunately the `poll` has the same issue.

---

EDIT

There are several possible solution and I have not sufficient information about your application. Following changed can be considered:

- Use `epoll` instead of `select` if you are on linux or other modern polling mechanism if you on another OS. `select` is quite old function and it was designed in time when threading was not considered seriously.
- Establish a communication channel between the select thread and the keep-alive thread. When keep alive thread detects a dead peer then don't close the socket itself but instructs the select thread to do that. Typically it can be done through a local socket. The local socket is added to select descriptor set and when the keep-alive thread writes something to it the select thread wakes up and can take an action.

Comment: Thanks! As usual, I should have better RTFM ... Having said that, how can you use a select() with no timeout and handle the problem that happens when the peer goes dark ?

Comment: my app have to run on Windows, OSX and Linux, so just epoll will not work (I can of course #ifdef various options) but the addition of a local socket and select on it will work. thanks !